# Knex.js default max pool leads to Error: ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, knex.js

We have 30 DigitalOcean droplets, each one for web CRM user, they are sharing the same MySQL database with knex.js.
With few additional users we getting errors:

- "ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections"
- "Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?"
- "Packets out of order. Got: 1 Expected: 0"

MySQL hosted at separate server with 4Gb of RAM and there is plenty of free RAM and CPU (over 50%).

In our nodejs app knex referenced as singleton:

```
const knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
        host: mySqlHost,
        user: mySqlUser,
        password: mySqlPass,
        database: mySqlDb
    }
})
module.exports = {
    knex
};
```

So why its ever possible to reach connections limit even with default 150 max connections for our MySQL (since we speaking about 30 users, they do pretty many reads and writes but its 30 users after all)?!

According to http://knexjs.org/#Installation-client "connection pool has a default setting of a min: 2, max: 10 for the MySQL and PG libraries" - is it safe to increase it to i.e. 50?! Knex docs poorly explained theirs pool concept, instead they referencing https://github.com/vincit/tarn.js for "more details" and there are no any details about MySQL.

Any help highly appreciated.

p.s. We realize that sharing database will lead to performance issues but we were thinking to migrate it when we reach thousands of users and from common sense its what we can expect from MySQL. Now we have performance issues with 30+ users.

Answer (score 1):

> We have 30 DigitalOcean droplets, each one for web CRM user, they are sharing the same MySQL database with knex.js. With few additional users we getting errors:

If I understood correctly from here https://www.digitalocean.com/products/droplets/ are separate virtual servers. So if you are running 30 separate node processes initializing the "same" knex instances, then there is no way how you could actually share the same singleton knex instance between them. Each node process initializes its own copy of it.

So when you have created a 30 knex instances and by default knex initializes with pool size 10, there is max 300 connections tried to be created to the DB.

> According to http://knexjs.org/#Installation-client "connection pool has a default setting of a min: 2, max: 10 for the MySQL and PG libraries" - is it safe to increase it to i.e. 50?! Knex docs poorly explained theirs pool concept, instead they referencing https://github.com/vincit/tarn.js for "more details" and there are no any details about MySQL.

There is nothing MySQL specific to tell and no reason why knex should duplicate `tarn.js` library's (nor mysql database / driver's) documentation.

It is safe to increase it to any number that is allowed by your database configuration. Though in your case if you are running 30 knex instances, the maximum connections should be 30 times less than the databases hard limit.

Dealing with multiple knex processes connecting the same database is a bit complicated and I would just consider raising mysql server's connection limit to 500 or something for it to be able to serve your 30 droplets which each might use 10 connections at max.

> p.s. We realize that sharing database will lead to performance issues but we were thinking to migrate it when we reach thousands of users and from common sense its what we can expect from MySQL. Now we have performance issues with 30+ users^

Sharing the same database might or might not lead to performance issues... it depends completely what type of queries are made to the DB.